# Whitescreen (500 error) with Civimail

Tags: civimail, wsod

As best I can tell, the menu link for a new mailing:

https://mysite.org/civicrm/mailing/send?reset=1
Redirects to https://mysite.org/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new

But this fails as a white screen.

The console tells me:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) GET https://mysite.org/civicrm/a/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Any ideas what's causing this? The same problem is true for A/B mailings.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [How do I debug CiviCRM when I hit a blank page / white screen / fatal error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/civicrm-is-showing-a-blank-page-white-screen-how-do-i-debug-this/6400) which has instructions for debugging PHP when you run into a blank screen.

Comment: Turns out there was a .js conflict with the Pogstone Module (drupal). Removing this module fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Odd that a JS conflict caused this symptoms, WSoD is usually a PHP conflict. Do you mean Pogstone's Fancy Tokens?Might be worth reporting against [the extension](https://github.com/sgladstone/com.pogstone.fancytokens/issues) or [CiviCRM](https://issues.civicrm.org) to help get the conflict fixed. Should you want to contribute further you can offer to sponsor the work.