# Webform 'previous page' button gives 500 server error

Tags: webform-civicrm, error, webserver

W7 Pro SP1
Firefox v.42, IE11, Chrome 46

The version of CiviCRM I’m using has a multipage Webform that I’m having problems with.

Everything works fine as long as I don’t try to use the form’s ‘previous page’ button, but if I do I get an HTTP 500 Server Error

With Firefox I initially get a ‘white screen of death’ (an empty browser – address field, bookmarks bar etc all there, but no content). If I then try the browser’s back button I get a “Document Expired” error message & if I keep clicking the browser’s back button I get back to the form’s ‘Begin’ page

I’ve tried it in Chrome & I get a “Server error 500” message & in IE I get ”HTTP 500 Internal Server Error”

My understanding is that a “500server error” is a very general error message, just saying that there’s a problem with the/a server....so, not that much help really!

My regional branch of the organisation is run by/hosted by another organisation, so to access the database I’m going via the host orgs server as well as the server at the parent organisation (Healthwatch England), which is where the database is & I don’t have admin access to either of them.

After searching for info on this I’ve tried increasing the cache size in firefox, but it hasn’t helped. I’m not sure what else to try.....has anyone come across anything like this before & resolved it?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The instructions in [CiviCRM is showing a WSoD - how do I debug this?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/civicrm-is-showing-a-blank-page-white-screen-how-do-i-debug-this/6400#6400) will apply to your situation, even though you aren't hitting a WSoD. If you [increase the debug settings on your site](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468), the 500 error may be slightly more informative information. If you can obtain access to view error logs on the server, the origin of the issue should quickly be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

Check your civicrm log file under ../files/civicrm/Configlog/.

Answer (score 1):

A 500 Server error will in most cases give a PHP error message in the log files. Are you able to look into the apache/nginx error logging? Or ask people who can?

That would help finding out what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just an end user so I don't have access to the server or any logs. Because I kept encountering the error even when the developers said it was sorted I thought I'd look into it myself & maybe pass on whatever I found out, but they finally got it sorted yesterday afternoon, though I've no idea what they did as I can't communicate directly with them.

Thanks anyway for your answers guys.