# 500 server error when creating entity reference field where entity is CiviCRM Contact

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity, entity-reference

I'm creating a new content type and want the fields to largely be CiviCRM Contact fields.

As I was adding a new Entity Reference field, I saved the field, selected the Target Type as CiviCRM Contact, and then clicked on 'Save field settings', but after about 1 minute of waiting, the server returned a 500 server error.

I can skip that step by clicking over to the widget tab and saving there, but when I go back to edit that field from the list of fields, I get the same error.

Other integration with Civi seems to be working okay.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: Try some of the [approaches for debugging recommended here](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error)? You're more likely to get an informed reply if the question gives sufficient detail about the error.

Comment: what version of civicrm_entity ? I haven't heard of a report for this functionality, and I've used it many, many times myself.  Please include any messages from the drupal or php logs