# Why would bounce processing put all emails into CiviCRM.ignore mailbox?

Tags: civimail

I did a first mailing and then got the bounce processing job working.  It just moved all the bounce responses (about 100) to the ignore mailbox and did not mark any of my contacts.  How do I tell what went wrong? There is no info in the log other than saying that it rand the job successfully.

Also I got emails of the form:
To: u.68.3087.7ed8aa555f763f19@californiacalvary.org
iOS Mail sent this email to unsubscribe from the message “One Week To Go!”.

Should these get processed?

Comment: The spelling in `californiacalvary.org` catches my eye (sorry, I'm like that). I wonder if your CiviCRM is ignoring the bounce emails because it's configured to expect bounces to `californiacavalry.org`? Looks like you have both domains registered - ✝ vs   ?

Comment: Interesting point.  The person who came up with the name misspelled it and being a lousy speller I just trusted.  We have both domains with the calvary one parked on the correct spelling of cavalry.  It does seem that the bounced emails are to the wrong spelling.  I must have something still configured the other way.

Comment: Worth eliminating. If you enable debugging on your site, debug log will show when CiviCRM ignores some emails. [See relevant code here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d40b6649e8af7fa55a5a71beee3483cdf6c68bf3/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L238), look for `markIgnored()`.

Comment: Suggests either CiviCRM [failed to parse the email](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d40b6649e8af7fa55a5a71beee3483cdf6c68bf3/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L244), or [didn't match recipient](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d40b6649e8af7fa55a5a71beee3483cdf6c68bf3/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L189) (possibly b/c wrong domain?).

Comment: Being a newbie, I am not sure how to turn on debugging.  I tried Administrator->Debugging and Error Handling and turned on debugging. There is no additional output in the Bounce job log.

Comment: Administer > System Settings > Debugging & Error Handling will log debug output to the CiviCRM debug log. This is a file on your webserver's disk. See http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error/6400#6400 and look for "debug log".

Comment: You are definitely correct, its the bad domain that is causing the problem.  I was able to fake up an email with the right domain and it got processed.  Now I need to figure out why that domain is being used, I cannot find it in any of the places where you set email addresses, etc.

Comment: I turned on debugging and found the log (not where the docs said it would be but here: www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.7994af42d5e2f8c96986ad92.log).  No output is generated when I run the bounce job and my attempt to patch the 100 bounce messages did not work for some reason, it would be nice to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like CiviCRM uses [the domain specified in the bounce mailbox settings](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d40b6649e8af7fa55a5a71beee3483cdf6c68bf3/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php#L160) to generate a regex to match incoming bounce messages.

From the info in your question, I suspect CiviCRM is directing bounces to a (subtly) different domain name. As a result, it doesn't think the bounces are intended for CiviCRM to process, and moves them to the ignored folder (as CiviCRM would with other "not for me" email).

See your mail account settings (Admin > CiviMail > Mail Accounts).

Try ensuring both the return address and site domain match, and see if the problem persists.

Once correctly configured (or, temporarily misconfigured to match the misspelled inbound address!), you can move those messages back from the CiviCRM.ignored mailbox to the INBOX, and re-process them.

Comment: Apparently the misspelling persisted after a domain change, possibly cached.  It is now gone.  I would hate to have that domain reinstalled.  I am planning on downloading and editing the emails to put the correct domain in them and then sending them back.  Do you happen to know if the bounce processor will handle multiple bounce info in one email or do they have to be separate emails?

Comment: You should [mark your question here as answered](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) :) ... I feel like it should be possible for you to reconfigure CiviCRM temporarily to accept the "wrong" domain for those bounces, move them from `CiviCRM.ignored` to `INBOX`, run the bounce processor, then configure CiviCRM back to use the "proper" domain. Downloading and uploading the previous set of bounces might not go as smoothly as you expect. (I don't know, haven't tried.)

Comment: I am not clear where to change the domain.  It is not clear what it uses to generate the X-CiviMail-Bounce domain.  Is it the bounce email address or the domain of the site? When I switched my site from my hosting domain to my real one it was down till someone went in and edited the database, so I will not casually change it again.  If there are specific instructions on exactly what I should change I will do that.

Comment: Ok.  It seems that sending the mail to the b. generated address does the trick.  Glancing through the code it looked like just having the X-CiviMail-Bounce record should be sufficient, but I guess not.

Comment: Yay! Good work for persisting :D