# Fresh installation of CiviCRM/Wordpress not working, showing white screen

Tags: wordpress, windows

Fresh version of Wordpress, CiviCRM installation was done successfully, but when I want to open the CiviCRM dashboard.. it didn't work!!

Any help!
Running on IIS

[image]

Comment: The message from the server seems to be:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hi Azzam, I suppose you run the latest and greatest (4.7.15). I suspect a PHP error under the hood. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error/6400#6400 explains how you can find it.

Comment: The debugging guide @Kainuk posted is great. Definitely check it out.

Comment: Hi @Kainuk, I added - <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); - to the index of WP, but nothing appeared. http://image.prntscr.com/image/af7abfefb7e5400f95d885f40d99668d.png

Comment: The screen dump you added shows that it is not able to load a lot of files (css and javascript). Are these files on the filesystem. You are using Internet Information Sever. Maybe you have to add path mapping.

Comment: @Kainuk they are on the filesystem and all plugins work perfect except CiviCRM.