# CiviCRM upgrade from 4.2.7 to 4.7.13 fails to show any report

Tags: civireport

CiviCRM was updated from 4.2.7 and right now is even updated to 4.7.16 but when we try to get reports and even try to click on "Refresh Results" it shows nothing, not even an error about it. The original site still has CiviCRM 4.2.7 and is able to show all reports with no trouble. I've been looking for any file, database table or anything that might be missing and needs to be updated but can't find what is causing this, any ideas what might be?

Regards,

Comment: Please update your question to indicate which reports you tested?

Answer (score 1):

As I said to your previous post about the same topic here: [What tables are used for civicrm reports?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17281/what-tables-are-used-for-civicrm-reports)

> 4.2->4.7 is a huge upgrade. Swathes of tables - including Activities and Settings - have changed. If you have any custom reports or
>   extensions these definitely will need to be upgraded without a doubt.

As ErikH said:

> Assuming you are using customized reports and do not have a
>   CiviCRM/PHP developer in your staff, you have to find a CiviCRM
>   expert/developer to do this for you

Upgrading these reports will require a coder to change their code to point them to the new database tables used by CiviCRM. There's no workaround. Code for custom reports will need to be changed. Tell your next developer to use the CiviCRM API if possible!

Answer (score 1):

I would check the CiviCRM log files.  [Find them here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories).  Also try steps listed here: [How do I debug CiviCRM when I hit a blank page / white screen / fatal error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, the connection between the report URL and the executing report PHP class is stored in the option tables. Does following query return any results?

```
select  *  FROM civicrm_option_value v
,                  civicrm_option_group g
where   g.id = v.option_group_id
and     g.name = 'report_template'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help, also seems CiviCRM 4.2.7 doesn't have some tables that 4.7.13 does have and it might be the problem but even creating new activities we get no reports shown.