# What tables are used for civicrm reports?

Tags: joomla, civireport, database

I need to know what tables and fields are used for the CiviCRM reports, I've been dealing for several weeks trying to see why an updated site from CiviCRM 4.2 to 4.7.16 on Joomla is not showing any reports, I need to see if several tables changed or fields and where to look into why they are not showing up as they don't show any errors, they only show no result at all. Thank you.

Comment: Different reports use different tables, because they report on different things!

Answer (score 1):

4.2->4.7 is a *huge* upgrade. Swathes of tables - including Activities and Settings - have changed. If you have any custom reports or extensions these definitely will need to be upgraded without a doubt.

This could be caused by a number of things.

1. Is this all reports, or just some? What are the names of the failing reports?
2. Please could you provide a screenshot?
3. Have you looked in the CiviCRM error logs and the Joomla! logs?

Comment: All reports are not showing up an I had to update the database for activities_contacts as it was blank so I had to move manually or the original activities_target table, even creating new ones won't show up, this is the original site: https://www.screencast.com/t/atjQkP55Bwp and this is the new site: https://www.screencast.com/t/ckFmcyLAHR also no errors show on joomla or civicrm error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with JohnFF, if you have customized reports and are moving from 4.2 to 4.7 you will almost certainly need to upgrade each and everyone of those reports.

Comment: How are they upgraded? This is the first time I had to deal directly with CiviCRM as I don't use it for personal projects and is a lot different 4.2 to 4.7 which is why I'm not sure if something else causes this.

Comment: Assuming you are using customized reports and do not have a CiviCRM/PHP developer in your staff, you have to find a CiviCRM expert/developer to do this for you? You can check the CiviCRM website (Find an Expert) for a list of partners near you?