# I can't install CiviCRM on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have two instances of WordPress (both running 4.7.4).

I have tried on one to install CiviCRM 4.6.27 and the other, CiviCRM 4.7.18. But, I get the same error: I try to install, I get all clear for the test to the DB and FileSystem, but after clicking on the « Check Requirements and Install CiviCRM » button, the browser just keep on loading the page with no success nor error messages.

I've install the plugin « Error Log Monitor » but I see nothing.
Also, the file civicrm.settings.php in the upload/civicrm folder doesn't exists.

I get this in my apache error log file:

```
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [INFO] [24.114.88.1:53124] Connection idle time: 91 while in state: 10 stream flag: 0,close!
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [NOTICE] [24.114.88.1:53124] Content len: 215, Request line: 'POST /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install HTTP/1.1'
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [INFO] [24.114.88.1:53124] Cookie len: 522, wordpress_efc9291620b9675fe124bc49dffdbee0=admin%7C1494220081%7Co5FUUWceWVXphjqDGUCDRikjuFvBeiZ9HSUbfxuKt7r%7Cf2762fb5071fa7a4a6f9dcc220b8402c3852569d55f33b951e942f84912bd462; _ga=GA1.2.118246024.1491536971; PHPSESSID=a81gmdbmehahoikdne82n1ehv2; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_efc9291620b9675fe124bc49dffdbee0=admin%7C1494220081%7Co5FUUWceWVXphjqDGUCDRikjuFvBeiZ9HSUbfxuKt7r%7C1f32a1947ae120408e5bd791386098b6fd1d01e0c86ab85ca52f7b885b6c2a1b; wp-settings-time-1=1493012558;wp-settings-1=deleted
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [INFO] [24.114.88.1:53124] HttpExtConnector state: 8, request body sent: 215, response body size: -1, response body sent:4529, left in buffer: 0, attempts: 0.
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [INFO] [24.114.88.1:53124] Lsapi connection state: 3, watching event: 25, respState: 5, m_iTotalPending:0, m_iPacketLeft:0, m_iCurRespHeader:8, req sent for 91 seconds,Total processing time: 91.
2017-04-24 01:44:09.900 [INFO] [24.114.88.1:53124] Abort request processing by PID:410255, kill: 1, begin time: 91, sent time: 91, req processed: 0
```

I'm on a provider's machine, a CentOS 6.0 64 bit. WordPress seams to work fine.

Issue? Where to look?

Regards,
   Antoine

Comment: See if there's any additional information in your PHP or webserver error logs? ([This answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error/6400#6400) may help too.)

Comment: We run a cPanel system specifically to do CiviCRM under WordPress, we're fairly experienced with cPanel, just getting started with Civi. My first question is do you have ssh access to the system?

Comment: Yes, SSH. This is a DirectAdmin, but I guess it's pretty the same.

Comment: I've put an addendum to original post.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/6278)

Comment: So you can ssh, find your WP directory, find plugins subdirectory, and Civi plug is installed? This is what mine looks like:

pwd
/home/invisiblecrm/public_html/wp-content/plugins

[root@civicrm plugins]# ls -l

drwxr-xr-x 4 invisiblecrm invisiblecrm 4096 Feb 23 15:59 akismet
drwxr-xr-x 6 invisiblecrm invisiblecrm 4096 Apr 15 11:41 arrow-twitter-feed
drwxr-xr-x 6 invisiblecrm invisiblecrm   89 Feb 23 16:35 best-import
drwxr-xr-x 9 invisiblecrm invisiblecrm 4096 Apr 12 17:56 caldera-forms
drwxr-xr-x 7 invisiblecrm invisiblecrm  148 Jan  4 17:11 civicrm

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini, what is your max_execution_time? I think the default may be 30 (sec) you may want to increase that.   Also I think at least with Civi 4.7 the install will try to install in the WP database, are you 1) selecting a different database (and user) or 2) using the WP one?  Are ANY tables ending up installed for Civi?

Comment: 1) same db 2) theses tables get created: civicrm_acl to civicrm_worldregion
(107 tables).

Comment: I checked with phpinfo(), and the execution_max is at 600(s).

Comment: That last line of your Apache log indicates that some process in the hosting environment is killing things off at 90 seconds. That may not be sufficient.