# Contribution page blank when SEF URLs on (Joomla)

Tags: civicontribute, joomla

I have a contribution page set up which used to work fine until one of the latest CiviCRM updates. Now the page is blank:

http://www.leftedgetheatre.com/donate

But if I access that same page using it's non-SEF URL, it works fine:

https://www.leftedgetheatre.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

I've turned on error reporting to Maximum and nothing is appearing.

I'm using Joomla 3.7.2 and CiviCRM 4.7.19 on PHP 7.0.16. But when I downgrade to PHP 5.6.30, the page appears OK. Are there any known issues with CiviCRM on PHP 7.0.16 ?

Comment: It sounds like there may be. If you [read these instructions to debug](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error/6400#6400), perhaps you may be able to add information to your question to help get this fixed? Identifying the exact error or supplying a backtrace (make sure to remove any sensitive details like payment processor config) should show the specific issue you're hitting.

Comment: Thanks. Chris. I should couldn't get anything to should up on the page or a PHP error log, but this is what showed up in my CiviCRM error log.

Jun 07 14:02:49  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)

Comment: Jun 07 14:02:49  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php(466): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#2 [internal function](): CRM_Utils_System_Joomla->permissionDenied()

Comment: #3 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:0))
#4 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(230): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))
#5 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(230): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()

Comment: #6 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#7 /home/leftedge/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#8 /home/leftedge/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(96): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#9 /home/leftedge/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()

Comment: #10 /home/leftedge/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/home/leftedge/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#11 /home/leftedge/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/leftedge/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#12 /home/leftedge/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#13 /home/leftedge/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()

Comment: #14 /home/leftedge/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationSite->doExecute()
#15 /home/leftedge/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()
#16 {main}

Comment: Hi @severdia, it's worth tracking down that PHP error log (check either your hosting provider help OR your OS / webserver documentation). A good place to paste snippets for debugging is a pastebin ([gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com) is my fave), and a good place for community support is [CiviCRM chat](https://chat.civicrm.org)! If you're really stuck, there are professional services available at https://civicrm.org/providers

Comment: As you'll have seen, you're hitting an "Access denied" message. Next step is probably to debug *why* this Joomla / CiviCRM site is giving access denied when hitting the contribute page with SEF URLs. Can't tell that from here.