# Server error 500 running cron.php in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/

Tags: wordpress, cron, 500

I'm getting 500 errors running something like this:

http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=cronuser&pass=mypass&key=mykey

This is an example of the error, which the web host tech support sent to me:

```
207.118.16.184 - - [11/Jun/2017:12:44:03 -0700] "GET /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=cronuser&pass=mypass&key=mykey HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

When I run the command in cpanel cron (using `wget -O -q -t 1`), the email that the Cron Daemon sends me looks like this:

```
--2017-06-11 14:05:01--  http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=cronuser
Resolving www.mysite.com (www.mysite.com)... 12.345.678.9
Connecting to www.mysite.com (www.mysite.com)|12.345.678.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2017-06-11 14:05:01 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

It looked to me like, in `cron.php`, the last three of the four requires shown below were wrong and needed an additional `../` to find the files. So I edited cron.php to change that, but continued to get 500 errors.

require_once '../civicrm.config.php';

require_once 'CRM/Core/Config.php'; --> changed to '../CRM/Core/Config.php'

require_once 'CRM/Utils/Request.php'; --> changed to '../CRM/Utils/Request.php'

require_once 'CRM/Core/JobManager.php';--> changed to '../CRM/Utils/Request.php'

So I created a test file, `cron_requires.php`, shown below. The hello prints out, the file_exists() statements find the files, but I'm still getting 500 errors:

```
<?php
echo nl2br ("hello\n\n");
$filename1 = '../civicrm.config.php';
$filename2 = '../CRM/Core/Config.php';
$filename3 = '../CRM/Utils/Request.php';
$filename4 = '../CRM/Core/JobManager.php';

if (file_exists($filename1)) {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename1 exists\n");
} else {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename1 does not exist\n");
}
if (file_exists($filename2)) {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename2 exists\n");
} else {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename2 does not exist\n");
}
if (file_exists($filename3)) {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename3 exists\n");
} else {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename3 does not exist\n");
}
if (file_exists($filename4)) {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename4 exists\n");
} else {
    echo nl2br ("The file $filename4 does not exist\n");
}
require_once '../civicrm.config.php';
require_once '../CRM/Core/Config.php';
require_once '../CRM/Utils/Request.php';
require_once '../CRM/Core/JobManager.php';
?>
```

===== added June 12 ======

Following advice to enable PHP errors, it seems perhaps CiviCRM is failing  to locate civicrm.settings.php on boot.

Specifically, the `error_log` in /plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/ has this:

```
[12-Jun-2017 20:15:37 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. Please boot with settingsFile, search, or CIVICRM_SETTINGS; or normalize your directory structure. in /path/to/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php(415): Civi\Cv\Bootstrap->boot()
#1 /path/to/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php(29): require_once('/path/to/...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php on line 125
```

Line 125 of civicrm.config.php is the `throw` statement here:

```
/**
   * Bootstrap the CiviCRM runtime.
   *
   * @param array $options
   *   See options in class doc.
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public function boot($options = array()) {
    if (!defined('CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH')) {
      $this->options = $options = array_merge($this->options, $options);

      $settings = $this->getCivicrmSettingsPhp($options);
      if (empty($settings) || !file_exists($settings)) {
        throw new \Exception("Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. Please boot with settingsFile, search, or CIVICRM_SETTINGS; or normalize your directory structure.");
      }
```

I am finding civicrm.settings.php in wp-content/uploads/civicrm/

Not sure how to proceed. Thanks in advance for any help!

WordPress 4.8  CiviCRM 4.7.17

Comment: You need to see what's going wrong to resolve this. I recommend you make sure you can view PHP errors (see [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error) for pointers). Either find your PHP error log and watch it while triggering the error, or set `display_errors` to `true` to see errors in the browser. From there, next steps will probably be much clearer.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisBurgess. I added some PHP error info at the end of my question. Perhaps this will give a clue to what's wrong?