# Every time someone hits "Confirm Contribution" their screen just goes blank

Tags: wordpress

Here is where it is happening http://bgcweberdavis.org/summerhays-golf-pro-am-scramble-payment/

It was doing it on the other payment forms I have so I disabled them on my site. Why won't it take the transaction?

Comment: what version of civicrm? new symptom? if so what changed?

Comment: There is a detailed answer on how to debug blank screen / "white screen of death" here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error - hope that's some help. Let us know how you get along?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for detailed error occurrence in civicrm logs, the file location of logs would be different based on the CMS you are using. Secondly you can follow below link to configure your settings file to display errors upon white death screen.
[How do I debug CiviCRM when I hit a blank page / white screen / fatal error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error)