# Civicrm inacessible after migration

Tags: migration

Today i had to migrate my civicrm installation from an old server to a new server

On the new server i found an existing drupal and civicrm ready. So i tried to proceed as in this guide

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

What i did is after copying my drupal and civi project after that i took the existing drupal Civi installation and started editing the civicrm.setting and setting.php based on the credentials they gived to me. After that i imported the databases from my old installation and removed the mentionned cache files. I stopped at step 13 cause i wasn't able to access any url related to Civicrm (drupal is working). Each time i get a screen similar to this.

[image]

Comment: Ali - this answer may be helpful: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error

Comment: Thank you chris i think the problem refering to the back trace is related to domain i checked the domain table and found it empty on the new server. I will try to import the backup i made from the new server civicrm installation and see if it works