# Just Upgraded to 5.0.1 and getting Guzzlehttp TypeError

Tags: wordpress, 5.0

Using wordpress 4.9.5, I upgraded civicrm 4.7.31 to 5.0.1

Site is running fine, but I getting this when accessing a contribution form.

> **TypeError thrown**
>
> Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 89

Anyone have any ideas?

I added the backtrace and here are the results:

```
Jun 06 11:14:49  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php(350): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#2 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(74): CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->permissionDenied()
#3 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(229): CRM_Utils_System::__callStatic("permissionDenied", (Array:0))
#4 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#5 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1246): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(295): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#8 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(319): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->render_single((Array:2), "", "civicrm")
#9 [internal function](): do_shortcode_tag((Array:7))
#10 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(197): preg_replace_callback("/\[(\[?)(civicrm)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\...", "do_shortcode_tag", "[civicrm component=\"user-dashboard\" hijack=\"0\"]")
#11 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(203): do_shortcode("[civicrm component=\"user-dashboard\" hijack=\"0\"]")
#12 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->prerender(Object(WP))
#13 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#14 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#15 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(726): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#16 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-includes/functions.php(960): WP->main("")
#17 /home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#18 /home/thefree/public_html/www/index.php(17): require("/home/thefree/public_html/www/wp-blog-header.php")
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Hi Bryant - can you give a backtrace by [turning on debugging](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/), or retrieving CiviCRM debug log ([instructions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error/6400#6400))? This provides more information on what Guzzle is choking on. **Be careful to redact sensitive information, eg payment credentials**, then post the relevant snippet of log to a pastebin or gist.github.com and link to it from your question. You only need to paste the backtrace from a single error.

Comment: Another suggestion: look for code *outside* of `civicrm-core` that may be interacting with Guzzle. (Ex: Maybe another WP plugin or Civi extension uses a different version of Guzzle?) You'd have to search the codebase for `GuzzleHttp` to find this. (The exact error-messages/symptoms of this problem would depend on happenstance.)

Comment: Hi @bryantwillis - can you let us know if you've gathered a Backtrace, Solved this issue or had any luck with Tim Otten's suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding, its been hectic and I just added a workaround by using direct links instead of civicrm shortcodes -- which we use to have.

Website is: www.thefreeclinics.org and the page in question is https://www.thefreeclinics.org/events-test-page/

I think it has something to do with the shortcodes... any ideas?  See the backtrace that I added to the original question.

Comment: The backtrace error doesn't match the original error you posted.  I suspect that you're not replicating the error here, but instead getting a different error, possibly because you were logged in the first time but not the second time?