# database Upgrade URL does not load Upgrade screen

Tags: upgrade

Civi 5.15.1, WP 5.3.2

We are in the process of upgrading Civi from 5.15.1 to 5.21, and are stuck at the "Upgrade the database" step in the upgrade instructions here:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

The first time we pasted the upgrade URL into our browser, we got a message saying our PHP version was out of date. So we upgraded it to version 7, and tried to reload the upgrade URL. Instead of an "Upgrade screen", we got the WP login page. Upon logging in, the WP Dashboard appeared, without any Civi upgrade button. Nor does the WP Updates page list Civi as an option.

We backed up our database before starting the installation -- should we just restore it, or are there other steps we should take first?

EDIT: We performed the above actions using Firefox 72.0.1 with the Standard Browser Privacy settings, but can make changes if need be.

Comment: Have you tried re-enabling CiviCRM in WP plugins?

Comment: CiviCRM 5.21.0 is listed under the Active filter, with only a Deactivate option given.

Comment: After logging in if you reload the upgrade page what happens?

Comment: We get the WP login page again. Checking "Remember me" doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Anything in logs in the configandlog folder?

Comment: Where is that folder located? There's nothing called configandlog in the WP sidebar or searching via our webhost's file manager.

Comment: If it exists it would be under the same place as Civi stores files/uploads

Comment: Yes, there are errors posted to ConfigAndLog every few seconds starting from when we initiated the upgrade, though they're probably too long to post here. The short version is :[callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

Comment: @john see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error or https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/ for some pointers on debugging mysteries situations like this. Be careful to remove any sensitive information (passwords, contact details) when posting for support.

Comment: There's also a separate No Such Field error that was posted more recently, but I'm not savy enough to decode any of these error messages.

Comment: Could you edit the message into the question - the short version is rather meaningless I’m afraid - you can put it as a snippet on gitlab at https://lab.civicrm.org

Comment: Was a solution found for this? I'm having the same problem. I successfully tested the upgrade with a cloned staging site without a hitch in the upgrade process. https://staging.islandnaturetrust.ca/ By following the CiviCRM Wordpress upgrade guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/ However, as soon as I attempted on the main site the updgrade database url loops back to the WP login page. https://www.islandnaturetrust.ca/ Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the upgrade url

```
http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1
```

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: I believe that's the URL I referred to in my OP as the "upgrade URL".

Comment: Can you paste the log to your question?

Comment: I think there would be too much to paste. We ended up restoring our website to a backup. Next time I try the upgrade, I'll post the log results to gitlab, per HomoTechsual's suggestion. Thanks, all!